# Parallel Calls Flux

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I want to call a function with one parameter, which returns a Mono in parallel and return the result as a LIst or Flux.

I am calling a function which returns a `mono<obj>` .

```
 return Flux.fromIterable(txnReqList)
                .parallel(5)
                .runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
                .flatMap(id -> getResponse(id))
                .sequential().collectList();
```

The response is `Mono<List<obj>>`
The call is working in a sequential manner and not in parallel. I put thread.sleep of one second in getResponse function and there are totally 3 objects in txnReqList/ The total time taken is 3.10 seconds.

Please help in making this simultaneous so that the call can happen in 1 second itself.

```
@Autowired
RSocketRequester requester;

@Override
public Mono < TransactionResponseDto > getResponse(TransactionRequestDto request) {
    //log.info(request.toString());
    return this.requester.route("post.transaction")
        .data(request).retrieveMono(TransactionResponseDto.class).log();
}

@Override
public Mono < List < TransactionResponseDto >> getAllResponse(TransactionRequestDto request) {
    TransactionRequestDto txnReqOrig1 = new TransactionRequestDto();
    txnReqOrig1.setExecOrder(1);
    txnReqOrig1.setProvider("PROV0");
    txnReqOrig1.setAcntId("0");
    txnReqOrig1.setTxnAmt(100.00);
    TransactionRequestDto txnReqOrig2 = new TransactionRequestDto();
    txnReqOrig1.setExecOrder(2);
    txnReqOrig2.setProvider("PROV1");
    txnReqOrig2.setAcntId("1");
    txnReqOrig2.setTxnAmt(101.00);
    TransactionRequestDto txnReqOrig3 = request;
    txnReqOrig3.setExecOrder(3);
    List < TransactionRequestDto > txnReqList = new ArrayList < TransactionRequestDto > ();
    txnReqList.add(txnReqOrig3);
    txnReqList.add(txnReqOrig1);
    txnReqList.add(txnReqOrig2);

    return Flux.fromIterable(txnReqList)
        .parallel(5)
        .runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
        .flatMap(id - > getResponse(id))
        .sequential().collectList();

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: would it be possible for you to share what the code is for `getResponse()`?

Answer (score 1):

The most important question you need to answer is what `getResponse` does.
Based on its name and the fact that you simulate its behaviour with a thread sleep, I'm assuming it does some **blocking IO** operation. **Parallel scheduler is not intended for this purpose**, it is intended for CPU intenstive operations. For this reason it has as many threads as many CPU cores are available (or sometimes multiplied by some low number).

Blocking IO operations should be offloaded to an **elastic scheduler** like below:

```java
return Flux.fromIterable(txnReqList)
           .flatMap(id -> Mono.defer(() -> getResponse(id)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic()))
           .collectList();
```

Elastic thread pools are able to "scale" based on the load.

However, the most reactive approach would be if you could use some **non-blocking IO** library (Spring WebClient, R2DBC, etc.) in your `getResponse` method. In that case you would **not need to worry about schedulers and threads** at all and you would have a highly scalable solution.

Also, one more note in reactive world you can simulate latency using `Mono.delay`. If you have non-blocking IO you can use `Mono.delay` for testing purpose. If you have blocking IO then `Thread.sleep` is the correct approach.

Comment: Hi Martin, Thanks for the update but its not fixing my problem still. I am calling a Rsocket API which returns a Mono Object. I need to iterate through a list and invoke the Rsocket API and collect the results . I want to do this in parallel. But still the getallresponses is working in serial manner only

Comment: Rsocket is good because it's non-blocking. Why do you think it is not working? Thread.sleep is not a good simulation for Rsocket. Did you try Mono.delay? Can you share the exact code that produced the unexpected latency?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example I've thrown together that demonstrates parallel processing of elements produced by a Flux.

```
Mono<List<Integer>> listMono = Flux.range(1, 5) <-- produces 5 events
            .parallel(5) <-- runs all 5 in parallel
            .runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
            .doOnNext(id -> slowTask()) <-- sleeps for x seconds
            .doOnNext(System.out::println) <-- prints out the id
            .sequential()
            .collectList();

StepVerifier.create(listMono.then())
            .verifyComplete();
```

When this code is run you will see the duration of execution is x where x is the number of seconds `slowTask()` takes. If this was not in parallel but in fact sequential, the execution would take 5x.

Let me know if you can run this code snippet and whether or not you see the same behaviour described as above?

Comment: Hi Michael. 
Thanks for your input. I have updated the question to include the sample code as well. Can you please review now.

Comment: I just want to make multiple simultaneous calls to the getResponse() function using a list of objects and send back the response in a Flux / list. . GetResponse takes in a parameter as well.